# Calculating partitions using multiplication rule

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A teacher wants to create 4 study groups of 5 students from a class of 20 students. How many ways are there to do this? The answer is $\binom{20}{5}\binom{15}{5}\binom{10}{5}\binom{5}{5}$. I don't understand why each term is multiplied together. $\binom{20}{5}$ ways to form the first group.. and $\binom{15}{5}$ for the second.. shouldn't it be $\binom{20}{5} + \binom{15}{5}+\binom{10}{5}+\binom{5}{5}$?

Using the answer given, does this mean that group order matters in the final study groups?

Comment: To understand why you'd multiply instead of add, try taking an example with smaller numbers. For example, try listing out how to divide six students into three pairs.

Comment: If the groups are indistinguishable (other than by their members), then I think the given answer is still wrong--it should be divided by $4!$.  However, this is separate from the issue the OP is raising.

Comment: Why multiply instead of add? The number of ways the first group is formed $20 \choose 5$ - clear till there. For each of the possibility for the first group, how many possibilities exist for the second group? That's $15\choose 5$ and since this is the number of possibilities of the second group for EACH of the possibilities of the first group, the total is the product of the two.

Comment: The multiplication rule is best understood by the tree diagram (http://www.milefoot.com/math/discrete/counting/images/treediagram.gif) each next branch you are multiplying

Comment: With this you can see that why the answer is still wrong because this overcounts the different type of break of up in groups because it implies order of groups matter ad paw88789 was pointing out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because we use multiplication theorem in case of dependent events and addition theorem in independent event. Clearly some students selected for a group cannot be selected for another group. But suppose selecting three flavours of icecream for yourself, even if you take one flavour,you can sleect any flavours for other two choices, here choices are independent,. and you use addition theorem here.