# If 6 different books are to be divided among 3 libraries, each containing precisely 2 books, how many possible divisions are there?

Tags: combinatorics

The way I reasoned was that for the first library, there are ${6 \choose 2}$ choices. Then for the second and third libraries, there are ${4 \choose 2}$ and ${2 \choose 2}$ choices respectively.

So in total there are ${6 \choose 2} * {4 \choose 2} * {2 \choose 2} = 90$ available divisions. However some classmates have added the terms rather than multiplying them together to get 22 possible divisions as their answer. Which operation is the correct one in this situation, and how should I know when to add or multiply the combinations in general?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/941680/calculating-partitions-using-multiplication-rule

Answer (score 2):

> $$\binom 62\binom42\binom22$$

They are dependent, if you select two books for library one, you cannot select them for others and so on.